# When does having a service layer make no sense?

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller, architecture

Having all your business logic in one place comes with various benefits. It makes your logic clean and easy to debug. However, I feel that it does not scale well under some circumstances.

For example,

```
class Book{
    String a, b......z;
}
```

My book class has 26 fields ( a thru z). For searching alone, there are 2^26 possible ways to query.

If I were to write a service class (repository) for this :

```
interface BookRepo{
     List<Book> findById(int id);
     List<Book> findByA(String a);
     List<Book> findTop10ByADescending(String a);
     List<Book> findByBAndCAndDAnd....Z(String a, b, c,d, e....z);
     ....
}
```

As you can see, it is absurd since there are so many combinations of search variable possible, not to mention sorting, and paging variables that may come into the picture.

If my application is so flexible such that for a given "Resource", user can filter any field, sort by anything. Shouldn't I skip service layer completely?

I have tried writing a "generic" service layer, it is not easy in statically typed language. In addition, if your service layer now lets everything through, there is no point having it there.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not really related to existing vs missing a service layer. your problem is caused by bad data structure and/or repository design.

if you want to filter by all possible combinations of 26 letters then think about creating queries dynamically and/or make many-to-many relationship between letter and book rather than having 26 fields inside a book. then you will have constant and small number of repository methods and you can easily add new letters.

if your application doesn't need service layer then you don't have to add it. but if you don't have it and your application grows it's harder to spot the moment when it's needed. instead people tend to put service-logic into controllers and/or repositories. especially when you work in a team